# BitNami DjangoStack on Amazon EC2

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have been trying this for days now, I've uninstalled and reinstalled at least 10 times. I am running BitNami DjangoStack on Amazon EC2. I have everything installed correctly, all my settings files made correctly (I know this because I ran them on my localserver before even considering uploading them to EC2) and for some reason I cannot get past the errors. I am getting multiple different errors, usually changing after I refresh the page every time. I'll get an error "Template Does Not Exist" when I know it does, I have the TEMPLATE_DIR setting correct and everything, it's almost like Django isn't reading my settings file at all.

Also, when i go to the Django Admin panel, sometimes my "Registration Profiles" section will be there, and other times its not. I can sit there and refresh the page and watch the section come and go.

AND when I refresh the page I sometimes get a "Page not found" error, which displays all the defined urls in myproject.urls, and it is only showing the admin urls, which those are clearly not the only urls specified...

I feel like BitNami DjangoStack is confused and cannot figure out how to work at all. If the errors are changing constantly and things are working then not working with every page refresh, what could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered you in answers.bitnami.org with the following:

If django shows "Template does not exist", it may be looking into the wrong directory. You can figure this out enabling debug mode ( DEBUG = True ) and reading the log shown when you try to access the affected web page, under the "Template-loader postmortem” section.

Please, check also if you have followed the instructions in "How to start a Django project?" on the link below:

http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/Django